# Trying to bold titleLabel of UIButton in response to delegate method being called in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfielddelegate

I am working on an application where I am calling the UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string { }
```

I am successfully calling it, and within the method, I enable a particular button.  This is also working fine.  However, the problem I am facing is that I am unable to make the title on the button bold when the button is enabled.  I set the font in Interface Builder, and I'm trying to bold the title programamtically. Here is the relevant code that shows what I am doing:

```
        if ([keys count] == [_tireName count]) {

            [_doneButton setEnabled:YES];//this line works
            [[_doneButton titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:28]];//this line does nothing


        } else if ([keys count] < [_tireName count]){

            [_doneButton setEnabled:NO];//this line works
            [[_doneButton titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:28]];//this line does nothing

        }
```

Ignore the "if" clause itself.  I want the text on the button to be bold when the button is enabled, and I want the text on the button to be "normal", when it is disabled.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what font you use? for example: helvetica?

Comment: If you are using iOS 6 and above you can use `- (void)setAttributedTitle:(NSAttributedString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state`.

Comment: What UIControlState would I use?

Comment: why don't you answer for my question when i m trying to help you

Comment: @incmiko: My apologies.  I'm using System 24.0 which I set in Interface Builder.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me how I would use the method (void)setAttributedTitle:(NSAttributedString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state ?

Comment: See this solution i have pasted there hope it will help.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72025858/10637692

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
_doneButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:24];
```

this will make your text bold, because you are using system font, which is helvetica. I hope it helps

Answer (score 30):

If you're using the standard fonts and want to make it bold, this is cleaner:

```
[_doneButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]];
```

This way, you don't have to worry about the font family or size.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3**

```
doneButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28, weight: UIFontWeightBold)
```

The following weights are available:

```
UIFontWeightUltraLight
UIFontWeightThin
UIFontWeightLight
UIFontWeightRegular
UIFontWeightMedium
UIFontWeightSemibold
UIFontWeightBold
UIFontWeightHeavy
UIFontWeightBlack
```

Note Apple's documentation, though:

```
// Beware that most fonts will _not_ have variants available in all these weights!
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to BooTooMany's answer, but I found that it actually changed the size when used in a UIButton.

I used:

```
[_doneButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:_doneButton.titleLabel.font.pointSize]];
```

That way, it keeps the same font size as what it started with, just makes it bold